# Can't access postgres extention created in docker entrypoint file, until I manually created it in psql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, timescaledb

I'm trying to use the timescaledb extension, and so I'm running their [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/timescale/timescaledb/).

In the last line of my docker entrypoint file, I run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
```

I verify that it's available for use with `\dx` in psql. As soon as I try to make use of the extension, I get:

> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I find I have to add it manually by `exec`ing into psql and running `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;`

What's wrong with my entrypoint? Why do I have to manually create the extension after the container is built and running?

Edit: here's the full entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER test_user PASSWORD 'password123';
    ALTER USER test_user WITH SUPERUSER; --needed to create timescaledb extension
    CREATE DATABASE testdb OWNER test_user;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO test_user;
    CREATE DATABASE tsdb OWNER test_user;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE tsdb TO test_user;
    ALTER USER test_user CREATEDB;
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
EOSQL
```

Comment: Could you share your entrypoint script please?

Comment: I've edited to add the entrypoint script now.

Comment: I don't see any postgresql server startup in your entrypoint. That makes me think that the actual postgresql daemon is not running when the entrypoint is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know docker, but this seems only related to Postgres, not Docker itself

---

`create extension` will create the extension in database `psql` is currently connected to. Seeing the script, this is most probably the default database `postgres` that you connect to.

So the extension will be created in the `postgres` database, **not** in the `testdb` database.

You have two options on how to change that:

#### 1. Use the `template1` database

Anything created in the `template1` database will automatically be created in every database created afterwards. So if you connect to the template database and run the `create extension` before creating the test database, the extension will automatically be available:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --dbname=template1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
    CREATE USER test_user PASSWORD 'password123';
    ALTER USER test_user WITH SUPERUSER; --needed to create timescaledb extension
    CREATE DATABASE testdb OWNER test_user;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO test_user;
    CREATE DATABASE tsdb OWNER test_user;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE tsdb TO test_user;
    ALTER USER test_user CREATEDB;
EOSQL
```

Note that the extension is created before anything else. The actual order isn't that important, the only thing that is important is that it's done *before* creating a new database.

#### 2. Connect to the newly created database

Switch to the newly created database from within `psql` before you create the extension using the `\connect` command in `psql`

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER test_user PASSWORD 'password123';
    ALTER USER test_user WITH SUPERUSER; --needed to create timescaledb extension
    CREATE DATABASE testdb OWNER test_user;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO test_user;
    CREATE DATABASE tsdb OWNER test_user;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE tsdb TO test_user;
    ALTER USER test_user CREATEDB;
    \connect testdb
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
EOSQL
```

---

The main difference between the two methods is that with the first, the extension will be available automatically in all databases that are created in the future. Whereas with the second method it is only available in the `testdb`

---

Unrelated, but: the newly created user does not need the `superuser` privilege as the extension is created using the `postgres` user, not the newly created one.

Answer (score 3):

To chime in with the prior answer, the TimescaleDB extension is applied per database, so if you run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;` without first connecting to your desired database with `\c yourdatabase` it will apply the extension to the default database.  See http://docs.timescale.com/v0.9/getting-started/setup for the step-by-step instructions to apply after install.